# History object chicken-egg issue with react-router-redux routerMiddleware() and syncHistoryWithStore()

Tags: react-router, react-router-redux

If you want to issue navigation events via Redux actions, the [docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#what-if-i-want-to-issue-navigation-events-via-redux-actions) tell you to use the `routerMiddleware`.

To call `routerMiddlware()`, you need to provide it with a `History` object and the Redux store will not have been created yet (because Redux middlewares are applied during store construction).

Yet the [tutorial example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#tutorial) shows that you should call `syncHistoryWithStore()` to "wrap" your history object.

This presents a chicken-egg problem, because in order to call `syncHistoryWithStore()`, you need a `Store` object, but in order to get a `Store` object, you need to call `routerMiddlware()` with a `History` object.

I have worked around this by giving `routerMiddlware()` a non-wrapped history object, creating the store and then updating history like so:

```
history = syncHistoryWithStore(history, store);
```

Yet as I'm not familiar enough with the codebase, I'm not sure if this is problematic and/or if there is another way.

Is this how it should be done?